# Apply boost::asio::ip::udp in ipv6 link scope unicast udp client-server deamon, sometimes works, but sometimes not

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, ipv6

I have encounted a problem when implement a simple udp client-server with boost::asio::ip::udp.if I bind the server with a ipv6 link-scope unicast address, it works in some PC, but not in some other PC.

```
//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/format.hpp>

void test_udp_server(std::string const& host_, std::string const& port_)
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    boost::asio::ip::udp::socket socket(io_service);
    boost::asio::ip::udp::resolver resolver(io_service);
    boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint endpoint= *resolver.resolve(boost::asio::ip::udp::resolver::query(host_, port_));
    socket.open(endpoint.protocol());

    std::cout << "address:" << endpoint.address().to_string() << " port:" << port_ << std::endl; 

    boost::system::error_code e;
    socket.bind(endpoint, e);
    if (e)
    {
        std::cerr << "bind error:" << e.message() << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    //recieve from
    boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint remote_endpoint;
    char buffer[4096];
    unsigned int size;

    while (1)
    {
        memset(buffer, 0, 4096);
        size = 0;
        size = socket.receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(buffer, 4096), remote_endpoint);

        std::cout << "receive: " << std::string(buffer) << std::endl;
    }
}

void test_udp_client(std::string const& host_, std::string const& port_)
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    boost::asio::ip::udp::socket socket(io_service);
    boost::asio::ip::udp::resolver resolver(io_service);
    boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint dest_endpoint= *resolver.resolve(boost::asio::ip::udp::resolver::query(host_, port_));
    socket.open(dest_endpoint.protocol());

    int i = 0;
    boost::system::error_code e;

    while (i < 10)
    {
        std::string msg = boost::str(boost::format("udp message %d") % i);

        socket.send_to(boost::asio::buffer(msg.c_str(), msg.size()), dest_endpoint, boost::asio::detail::message_do_not_route, e);
        if (!e)
        {
            std::cout << "send: " << msg << std::endl;
        }
        else 
        {
            std::cerr << "send error: " << e.message() << std::endl;
        }

        i ++;
    }
}

int main(int ac, char* av[])
{
    if (ac != 4)
    {
        std::cout << "ac != 4" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    if (std::string(av[1]) == "c")
    {
        test_udp_client(std::string(av[2]), std::string(av[3]));
    }
    else if (std::string(av[1]) == "s")
    {
        test_udp_server(std::string(av[2]), std::string(av[3]));
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "av[1] != \"c\" and av[1] != \"s\"" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

complite it, and run as this:

```
./main s fe80::211:85ff:fe6c:44ac%eth0 100  #server, "s" means server,  
                                            #"fe80::211:85ff:fe6c:44ac%eth0" means your ipv6 address
                                            #and 100 is port
./main c fe80::211:85ff:fe6c:44ac 100       #run it in another ssh or shell
```

but the result is :

**- 1 udp server never receive the msg sended by client**

```
[root@wangsu Tmp2]# ls<br>
main  main.cpp  main.o  Makefile<br>
[root@wangsu Tmp2]# ./main s fe80::211:85ff:fe6c:44ac%eth0 100<br>
address:fe80::211:85ff:fe6c:44ac%eth0 port:100<br>
```

**2 udp client, has send msg successfuly**

```
[root@wangsu Tmp2]# ./main c fe80::211:85ff:fe6c:44ac 100<br>
send: udp message 0<br>
send: udp message 1<br>
send: udp message 2<br>
send: udp message 3<br>
send: udp message 4<br>
send: udp message 5<br>
send: udp message 6<br>
send: udp message 7<br>
send: udp message 8<br>
send: udp message 9<br>
```

**3 when i open tcpdum , it really captured the msg sended by client**

```
[root@wangsu Tmp2]# tcpdump -i lo udp and host fe80::211:85ff:fe6c:44ac<br>
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode<br>
listening on lo, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 96 bytes<br>
10:55:41.215110 IP6 fe80::211:85ff:fe6c:44ac.59007 > fe80::211:85ff:fe6c:44ac.100: UDP, length 13<br>
10:55:41.215295 IP6 fe80::211:85ff:fe6c:44ac.59007 > fe80::211:85ff:fe6c:44ac.100: UDP, length 13<br>
10:55:41.215360 IP6 fe80::211:85ff:fe6c:44ac.59007 > fe80::211:85ff:fe6c:44ac.100: UDP, length 13<br>
10:55:41.215431 IP6 fe80::211:85ff:fe6c:44ac.59007 > fe80::211:85ff:fe6c:44ac.100: UDP, length 13<br>
10:55:41.215516 IP6 fe80::211:85ff:fe6c:44ac.59007 > fe80::211:85ff:fe6c:44ac.100: UDP, length 13<br>
10:55:41.215585 IP6 fe80::211:85ff:fe6c:44ac.59007 > fe80::211:85ff:fe6c:44ac.100: UDP, length 13<br>
10:55:41.215790 IP6 fe80::211:85ff:fe6c:44ac.59007 > fe80::211:85ff:fe6c:44ac.100: UDP, length 13<br>
10:55:41.215926 IP6 fe80::211:85ff:fe6c:44ac.59007 > fe80::211:85ff:fe6c:44ac.100: UDP, length 13<br>
10:55:41.216069 IP6 fe80::211:85ff:fe6c:44ac.59007 > fe80::211:85ff:fe6c:44ac.100: UDP, length 13<br>
10:55:41.216130 IP6 fe80::211:85ff:fe6c:44ac.59007 > fe80::211:85ff:fe6c:44ac.100: UDP, length 13<br>
```

**4 and this is my ifconfig:**

```
[root@wangsu Tmp2]# ifconfig<br>
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:11:85:6C:44:AC  
          inet addr:192.168.23.38  Bcast:192.168.23.255  Mask:255.255.255.0<br>
          inet6 addr: fe80::211:85ff:fe6c:44ac/64 Scope:Link<br>
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1<br>
          RX packets:1174940938 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0<br>
          TX packets:626463551 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0<br>
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100<br> 
          RX bytes:378565405153 (352.5 GiB)  TX bytes:126427805747 (117.7 GiB)<br>
          Base address:0x3400 Memory:fd000000-fd020000<br> 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback 
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0<br>
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host<br>
          inet6 addr: ::127.0.0.1/0 Scope:Compat<br>
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1<br>
          RX packets:188781410 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0<br>
          TX packets:188781410 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0<br>
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0<br> 
          RX bytes:582726106596 (542.7 GiB)  TX bytes:582726106596 (542.7 GiB)<br>
```

By the way ,before run the server and client , I had stopped the iptables.And more strange, in my another pc it runs ok.

so why?

Comment: If you try to bind only to the port, not to the host, does it work better then? I.e. skip all resolving and binding, just create the socket like this: `boost::asio::ip::udp::socket socket(io_service, boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint(udp::v6(), atoi(port_.c_str())));`

Comment: Thanks to Mr.Pileborg.As your advice, it now runs so healthy!But there's a pity that it not fitting my need completely.In fact, I want to allocate a sepecify num threads for each interface of my host to receive and deal with msgs,then I must bind interface to socket.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the solution provided in my comment, maybe you should try a similar solution that allows you to bind to a specific interface.

The problem, I think, is that you do a DNS query for the host and port, while you should just bind directly to the host address and port.

Something like this:

```
// First convert the address string to its binary form
boost::asio::ip::address_v6 address =
    boost::asio::ip::address_v6::from_string(host_);

// Create the endpoint
boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint endpoint(address, atoi(port_.c_str()));

// And finally create a bound socket
boost::asio::ip::udp::socket socket(io_service, endpoint);
```

Comment: TO global scope or loopback scope unicast ipv6 address, it will works well.But link scope is special!When using a link scope ipv6 address, you also need to point its interface,as "fe80::211:85ff:fe6c:44ac%eth0",or boost::asio::ip::udp::socket::bind

Comment: sorry, I'm new to ask quetion on Stack Overflow.<br>TO global scope or loopback scope unicast ipv6 address, it will works well.But link scope is special!When using a link scope ipv6 address, you also need to point out its interface,as "fe80::211:85ff:fe6c:44ac%eth0",or boost::asio::ip::udp::socket::bind will complains "Invalid Argument"!But if you input ipv6 with interface, then it will not pass boost::asio::ip::address_v6::from_string() func. So I use the resolver to resolve it, and it really works well in my home PC.But strange is that in my company PC it doesn't work!